# Using streams to find best way - Scheme

Tags: stream, matrix, scheme, racket

I'm relatively new to Scheme and I'm having a few problems with streams. I only know how to make a stream of natural numbers, nothing more complex. I thought maybe they'll be of use in this case. So, basically, I have this matrix:

[0 0 0 0 0 S 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 x 0 x 0]
[0 0 0 0 x 0 0 x]
[0 0 0 x 0 0 0 x]
[0 0 0 x 0 0 0 x]
[0 0 x x 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 D 0 0 0 0 0]

where x = accessible paths
S = source
D = destination

What I have to do is get from S to D by traveling only horizontally, vertically and diagonally one square at a time on the accessible paths. Until now, I've only created a list of positions that contains the source's position, the accessible paths and the destination's position.
Is there a way of choosing the correct path by using streams? And if that is too complex for me to understand, what other method do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that streams contribute substantially to an understanding of this problem.  What you have is a search problem--you're looking for a sequence of moves in a space of possibilities.  I would encourage you to take a look at [HtDP, section 28](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-35.html#node_chap_28) for a look at a very similar problem.

Comment: +1 Graphs for the win. :-) (Shamefully, I flunked a Google on-site interview because I didn't brush up on graphs.)